# Find out all SSL chain to root using PHP

Tags: php, openssl, certificate

I'm looking for a way to find all SSL chain from domain name to root.

I use openssl_x509_parse with stream_context_create. I got the certificate, issuer etc. From there I'm having a hardway finding the intermediate if any and root issuer.

Part of the print_r output is [authorityInfoAccess]. I figured I should find it there, so I parsed this line (the one containing CA Issuers not the one with OCSP) and processed it the same way. Sometimes I can see the root name, sometimes it gives me a direct link to cacert which I don't know how to parse.

Is there a way to recover intermediate and root everytime with openssl_x509_parse ?

Thank you :)